# Conveying the idea of "It goes without saying" with "Il va sans dire"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

When I studied French I was taught that the expression "[it goes without saying](https://grammarist.com/usage/goes-without-saying/)" is conveyed by "il va sans dire". Dictionaries confirm this. So for

> Of course, it goes without saying that you'll be paid for the extra hours you work.

I would say

> Bien entendu, il va sans dire que vous serez rémunéré pour les heures supplémentaires que vous faites.

But I have yet to hear a native speaker use "il va sans dire (que)" in colloquial speech. Is this expression used in France at all? Is it considered an anglicism or outdated?

What other ways exist to express a similar idea (i.e. that something is obvious)?

Comment: imo, to my spirit that expression fit well if used from a majordome or someone with highly manner,  but as you state France I will not answer :)

Comment: You would not say "bien entendu, il va sans dre que, etc.": "bien entendu" and "il va sans dire" express the same idea and are therefore redundant: choose one or the other, but not both.

Comment: When I went to Paris, I naïvely remarked to a restaurateur, "Paris c'est vraiment belle!" He shrugged: "C'est connu."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Il va sans dire* belongs to a rather formal level of speech, that is probably the reason why you have not come across it yet in day-day-interactions with native speakers. More frequent turns of phrase would use *évidemment*, *c'est évident*, *bien entendu*, *cela va de soi*, etc.

Comment: *Évidement/c'est évident* ne sont pas strictement synonymes de *Il/ça va s'en dire/il/ça va de soi*. Il y a des cas où on peut avoir besoin d'utiliser « Bien évidemment, il va sans dire ... ». Nothing formal about *il va sans dire*, true I don't use it everyday but to my mind "formal"  is  something else.

Comment: As “colloquial” language (which I agree with), isn't it rather some *INFORMAL* level of speech?

Comment: Une réponse qui coule de source

Answer (score 2):

*Il va sans dire* (or *Cela va sans dire* which I personally prefer) means *It is implicit*, *There is no need to say it*.

Comment: Mais... *ça va quand même mieux en le disant*... ;-)

Comment: “ça va quand même mieux en le disant” is a joke — I am not sure this remark helps the asker.

Comment: @dralpuop: not always a joke. It is sometimes used to emphasize and insist that what follows next is important. I am not sure that Talleyrand was joking when he used it.